# Get the dynamically added table values in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have my jsp file similar to the following:

```
<table>
<tr class="schedule">
    <td><input type="text" name="fromDate"</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="toDate"</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr class="fromTime">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fromHour"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr class="toTime">
                <td>
                    <input name="toTime"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="amount"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="totalAmount">
    <td><input type="text" class="totAmount"</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

New *schedule* rows get dynamically added and for each of this, there can be no.of *fromTime* and *toTime* tables. I need to get these values in my servlet. I know I could get the values of  *fromDate* and *toDate* through

```
String[] fromDates=request.getParameterValues("fromDate");
String[] toDates=request.getParameterValues("toDate");
```

I am looking to find out how I can retrieve *fromHour* and *toHour* values corresponding to its *fromDate* and *toDate*.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: where is your form tag ?

Comment: sorry, the html part is supposed to be inside form tag. I only wrote the related part @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when they created dynamically let them look like `"fromDate_1"` and `"toDate_1"`
and the corresponding time look like `"fromTime_1"` and `"to_time_1"` 
then the next scheduler to look like  `"fromDate_2"` and `"toDate_2"`
and the corresponding time look like `"fromTime_2"` and `"to_time_2"` 
and so and so

then in your servlet 
make a for loop to get them like

```
for (int i=1;i<100;i++){ //i dont think so the max value will be larger than 100
if (request.getParameterValues("fromDate_"+i)==null ){
break;
}else{
fromDate[i]=request.getParameterValues("fromDate_"+i);
}
}
```

and the same for every param you have

Comment: This seems to be a crude way of doing the needful. Is there a standard way of doing the same?